# Probability density to find the end of a double pendulum

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, probability

Given infinite time, is there a way to find the probability to find the end of a double pendulum at a given position? I am looking at a system with no damping (constant energy).

The bobs are point masses and the rods are massless. The masses of the two bobs are same and the length of the two arms are same. I don't know if ergodicity could be assumed to this problem. I'm interested in a system with chaotic behavior. (not assuming small angle approximation).

Although the system is chaotic, I think the probabilities are calculable.

I have seen a similar question on [this reddit post (from r/physicsgifs)](https://www.reddit.com/r/physicsgifs/comments/25zedh/chaos_and_the_double_pendulum_xpost_from_rphysics/) where one of the answers claim that the probability distribution is not uniform. I would like to know if this is true and why or why not?

[image]

This is a picture from the above link.

Comment: This isn't a bad question in principle, but you need to edit it with several clarifying details to get any useful answers.  Are you looking at the probability density with respect to position, or with respect to momentum as well (i.e., a phase space density)?  Are you looking at a single energy or a range?  Are you working in the small angle approximation?  Are you assuming ergodicity in the accessible region of phase space, or does that need to be shown?  Are the two arms of the pendulum the same length?  Do the two bobs have the same mass?

Comment: Is [this analysis](https://arxiv.org/pdf/nlin/0406018.pdf) of any use?

Comment: I guess you forgot to include the link to the picture's website. It might be helpful.

Comment: What does it mean for the "probability distribution to not be uniform"? Not be a uniform distribution (i.e., $p(x)=1/(b-a)$)? Or the space it covers in the image (i.e., what is filled in the region) be uniformly colored?

Comment: The probability distribution is not uniform means that probability at position 'a' is not equal to a different position 'b'. If probability was uniformly distributed then the image would have been uniformly colored.

Comment: Alright, it's not clear to me what is unclear about the image then . It's clearly not uniformly colored, so it's clearly not uniform.

Comment: Also, I won't see message without you adding `@KyleKanos` to the comment.

Comment: My question is how can we prove it from the laws of physics @KyleKanos